# JSON Error in iOS

Tags: iphone, json

i need to send json dictionary as parameter, i am using afnetworking. While using following code i am getting an exception:

```
  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", nil];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email":txt_email.text,@"password":txt_password.text,@"platform":@"iphone"};
    NSLog(@"params:%@",params);
    SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter=[[SBJsonWriter alloc]init];

    NSString *paramsDicJSONN = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:params];            
     NSString *str_url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@do_signup",BaseURLlogin];

   [manager POST:str_url parameters:paramsDicJSONN success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"offerJSON: %@", responseObject);
```

Exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [`AFNetworking` documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.4.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html#//api/name/POST:parameters:success:failure:) in regard to sending POST data.

`- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters ...`

The `parameters` argument expects an `NSDictionary`, not a JSON encoded `NSString`. Most likely just pass `params` and skip all the `SBJsonWriter` code.

Comment: Server will accept json format,if i pass it as params i will not get response.Any method to pass json dic as parameter

Comment: You will need to use a different method if you want to post a JSON String, this method requires a `NSDictionary`.